# Graphical examination for existence of 2nd order ODE given a solution curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given any solution curve $y(t)$, what are some graphical criterion to determine whether there *exists* some 2nd order linear, homogeneous, with continuous but possibly non-constant coefficients, to which the curve is a solution?

Each of the plots below show graphs of three functions $y(t)$. For which options do there exist a second order linear homogeneous ode with continuous but possibly non-constant coefficients to which all three functions are solutions of?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.

Upon closer inspection, I'll concede that (b) is in fact not a solution of the original question.

Note that the solution curves in (b) all differ by a constant. If there exists a second-order ODE that admits all of these curves as a solution, then it must also admit a constant as a solution.

In general, an IVP that admits a constant solution looks something like this

> $$ y''(t) + p(t)y'(t) = 0, \quad y(t_0) = y_0, \ y'(t_0) = 0 \tag{1} $$

where $p(t)\ne 0$.

If the ODE in $(1)$ has a non-constant solution, said solution must not have a zero derivative at any point (since if a solution has a zero derivative, it must be constant due to the Uniqueness Theorem). We see that the non-constant curves in (b) do not satisfy this, therefore (b) is not correct.

Comment: Thank you! I learn from this answer. Sorry for the confusion, my foundation is quite weak. Hope this post inspires some people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are (a), (c), (f).

Notice that the red graph $y_3$ of option (f) is exactly in the middle, so it is a linear combination of $y_1$ and $y_2$.In comparison of option (e), the red graph is not a linear combination of the other two, so we get three linearly independent solutions. But the solution space of a second order ODE has dimension two, so option (e) is not possible.

In option (d), the green curve and the red curve have common zeros, which is not allowed unless they are constant multiples of each other. If they were constants multiples of each other, they would have the same zeros.

*Please view my other answer for why option (b) is incorrect.

Therefore options (b), (d) and (e) are incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure that (b) is wrong? The solution space of that case could be one those curves, and a constant.

Comment: Also, your assertion that "linearly dependent solutions must be constant multiples of each other" is not necessarily correct. You can have 3 linearly dependent solutions where $y_3 = ay_1 + by_2$, but any 2 of them are still linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you. We could also refer to the form of any solution of a second order non-homogeneous ODE, which must have the form $y = c_1y_1 + c_2y_2 + Y$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are general solutions to the corresponding homogeneous equation and $Y$ is a particular solution. There is a specific way to calculate $Y$ using the method of Variation of Parameters that does not give the leeway to add a random constant at the end.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Take the equation $a(t)y''(t) + b(t)y'(t) = 0$. What are its solutions?

Comment: I have updated the solutions!

Answer (score 0):

The *Existence and Uniqueness Theorem* for second order ODE states that

> For the initial value problem 
>   
>   $$
> y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y = g(t),\qquad y(t_0)=y_0, y'(t_0)=y_0'
> $$
>   
>   where $p,q$ and $g$ are continuous on an open interval $I$ that contains the point $t_0$, there is exactly one solution $y=\phi(t)$ of this problem and the solution exists throughout the interval $I$.

For option (b) at $t=0$, we see that the solutions each take on different values, hence they cannot be solutions to the same initial value problem.

Comment: The solution $y = c_1 + c_2e^{-(b/a)t}$ is only true if $a$ and $b$ are constant, but they don't have to be. Try again.

Comment: Also, the above above theorem does not prove that (b) is incorrect, since the given solutions are solutions of different IVPs.

Comment: Thank you, but the question is really asking for all solution curves to be solutions of the same IVP. (b) was supposed to be easily factored out as an wrong answer.. The tricky ones were just comparing (e) with (f) and option (d). Please advise if you have some better explanations.

Comment: That's not what the original question was asking (all solutions of the same ODE, regardless of initial conditions). If that's not what you wanted to ask, please update the original question for clarification. Moreover, if this is the real question, then **none** of these options can be correct, since no curves share the same $y(t_0)$ and $y'(t_0)$. I would ask your instructor what the correct answer is before we go on.